# AWS Amplify + Appsync - Is it possible to use @connection transform to cascade delete related data?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, graphql, aws-appsync, aws-amplify

I am developing a web application using AWS Amplify and AppSync to read and write my data to DynamoDB tables. Using the [Amplify's GraphQL Transforms](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli/graphql?sdk=js), it is easy enough to establish a connection between data types using the `@connection` transform. I wish to know if it is possible to delete related data in a simplified or semi-automated way.

Supposing a simple blog example, where a user has a blog, which has posts, which in turn has comments owned by other users. If a post is deleted, I would like to delete the comments associated with that post. If a user is deleted, I would like to delete their blog(s), posts, and comments related to those posts, and any comment the user has left on other posts. This example is contrived in that perhaps it is desirable to have some of this data be maintained in some form. However, in some cases this behaviour is exactly what I am looking for.

When working with Prisma in the past, I used their [`@relation`](https://prisma-docs.netlify.com/docs/1.4/reference/service-configuration/data-modelling-(sdl)-eiroozae8u/#the-@relation-directive) directive to make a relationship similar to using Amplify's `@connection`.
However, in cases where I wanted cascading deletion, I would write something along the lines of:

```
type Post {
id: ID! @unique
  title: String!
  body: String!
  owner: ID!
  comments: [Comment!] @relation(name: "PostComments",
onDelete: CASCADE)
}
```

I could use and set the `onDelete` parameter to `CASCADE` or `SET_NULL` depending on how I wanted to handle it.

Is there a way to do something similar through Amplify? Of course I can write a bunch of VTL or Lambda resolvers to handle each case, but I wanted to check first if there is a faster / easier way to implement this.

Comment: Could you clarify how you were able to do this via VTLs? I'm having the same issue currently

Comment: Hey @JohnStone, so sorry. The project I was working on has come and gone. To be honest, I don't even recall if I ultimately got this behaviour working. It was a personal project I had been working on to explore this stack. I have since deleted my AWS account as the free trial was over, and moved to more mobile application development. I recall that VTL was a bit of a pain as I was unfamiliar with it, and so desperately wished I could just write it out with javascript. I believe it required this: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/pipeline-resolvers.html

Comment: Instead of creating a custom resolver in VTL you could achieve the desired result by using a direct lambda custom resolver. Here's some docs to go by:
- Intro article about it: https://www.timveletta.com/blog/2020-12-08-direct-lambda-resolvers-with-aws-amplify/
- Amplify docs: https://docs.amplify.aws/cli/graphql-transformer/function/
- AWS's announcement article: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/appsync-direct-lambda/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not yet supported natively by Amplify. As you said, you are able to replicate this behavior using pipeline resolvers & some VTL and then deploy that via the Amplify CLI or on your own. There are plans to allow you to write your own transformers to encode reproducible logic like this as a resolver (see https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/1060) as well as plans to move towards pipeline resolvers for all Amplify CLI projects (see https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-cli/issues/1055).

Comment: This is what I've been gathering from my research. Thank you for clarifying!